# NetBeans 8.02 hangs when i press enter

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, freeze

When I run my project and I try to press enter on a *JSP* page to create a new line it hangs for 2 minutes or more. Surprisingly this does not happen when the project is not running.

If I copy a blank line and paste it there is no hanging.

This happens only when a project is running. Java files are not affected by this. The first time that I open NetBeans all is ok. If I run the project the *JSP* files of this project are affected by this.

If I stop the project the problem persists.
*JSP* files of other projects are not affected by this.

Comment: I had some kind of similar issues as well some times ago. I think it as caused by the antivir software installed on that machine. Maybe that's a starting point.

Normally you should get a slowness report - at least for more recent versions of NetBeans. Any reason you don't upgrade?

Comment: The antivirus was not interferring at all. I upgraded to 11.3 the same day and the bug is not happening.

Comment: Just another hint for someone in the future: Sometimes it helps deleting the cache directory.